# Pepperflash massively impacting game performance on mouse click

Tags: flash, haxe, haxeflixel

I'm writing a flash game (swf v28) and I've noticed that when I play my game on the site (newgrounds.com), mouse clicks make the game extremely laggy if I am using a browser with pepper flash enabled.  It works fine when I'm playing on internet explorer.

Have any of you experienced this problem?  If so, can you suggest a work around?

game can be found here:  http://www.newgrounds.com/portal/view/675743